# matlab - number of occurrences in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have (n x n) matrix in Matlab. For example(n=3):

```
A=[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 1,9,9]
```

And I want to count number of occurrences for first n numbers (and create matrix B). 
Output:

```
B=[2,1,1]
```

Thank you.

Comment: If `A=[1,2; 3,1]` then do you `B=[2,1]` or `B=[1,1]`? i.e. are you counting within that column or in the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very elegantly with `bsxfun` and `sum`.

```
sum (bsxfun (@eq, A(1:n), A(:)))
```

However, I believe your example is incorrect. In your example matrix

```
A=[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 1,9,9]
```

the first 3 elements are not `[1 2 3]` but `[1 4 1]` since in Matlab elements are in Column-major order. If you want to check the first `n` elements from the first row, then you should instead do:

```
sum (bsxfun (@eq, A(1,1:n), A(:)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the stat toolbox, you can use `tabulate` ([doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html)), otherwise `countmember` ([matlab exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7738-countmember)) will do it.

```
TABLE = tabulate(A(:));
```

Comment: Suppose one would need something like `tabulate(A(ismember(A,A(:,1))))` to limit this to the first row values.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
  A=[1,2,3; 4,5,6; 1,9,9];

  for i=1:length(A)

      B(i) = length(find(A(1,i) ==A));   
  end
```

Comment: Though it is mentioned that the matrix is `nxn` using `length` is typically asking for problems. In this case I would go for something like `size(A,2)` to replace `length(A)`.

Comment: That is correct.  length(A(:,1)) will also work, to specify only the length of dimension 2.

Comment: If performance is an issue the `length(find` can probably be replaced by `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `ismember`:

```
[lia,lib]=ismember(A,A(1,:))
h=hist(lib(lib>0),1:size(A,2))
```

Comment: This returns `B = [2 1 6]`.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia I see now, using a histogram might not be so practical. Have changed the approach to `ismember`.